# Count number of string-instances in list from csv using for loop

Tags: python-3.x, string, loops, csv, count

Trying to count the number of times the words 'Male' or 'Female' appear in this column, my loop is not working and can't figure out why.

```
import csv

with open('obesity.csv', mode = 'r') as file:
    myreader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ',')
    for lines in myreader:
        male = 0
        female = 0
        gender = lines[0]
    
        for i in gender:
            if i == "Male":
                male += 1
            else:
                if i == "Female":
                    female += 1
                    print(male, female)
```

Comment: Are you sure it says `Male` and `Female`, not `Male `, `Male, `, `Male , `, `male`, etc?

Comment: Yes, I've checked to make sure the strings match exactly and with no leading or trailing white space

Comment: You reset `male` and `femal` counter inside the loop - so you set it to 0 for each _row_. move that outside the loop.

Comment: `gender = lines[0]` means gender is a string (the 1st column). `for i in gender:` iterates the string character wise - one character is NEVER equal to multiple characters. Please use print-statements to _debug_ your code before posting.